# Scala: why AnyVal appears here?

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections

Here is the code:

```
val m=scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Long]()
var i=m.get("foo")
i=i+i
```

Here is the error:

```
Error:(28, 9) type mismatch;
 found   : AnyVal
 required: String
    i=i+i
        ^
```

Why `i` suddenly becomes `AnyVal`? And why `String` is required here while values in my map are `Long`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this in the REPL?

```
scala> val m=scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Long]()
m: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Long] = Map()

scala> var i=m.get("foo")
i: Option[Long] = None
```

`i` is **not** a `Long`, but an `Option[Long]`, since `foo` may not be a key in the `HashMap`.

If I had to guess as to why it's saying `String` is required, it would be that the scala compiler is trying to implicitly convert `Option[Long]` `toString` in order to use the `+` method.

If you really want to double `i`, then you'll need to `map` the `Option`

```
i.map(x => x + x)
```

Which in this case is still `None`.

Comment: "i is not a Long, but an Option[Long], since foo is not a key in the HashMap." well, `i` would always be `Option[Long]`, even if `"foo"` were  a key in `m`. You probably meat "since foo may not be a key".

Comment: @KarolS Yes, that would be the correct way to say it.

Answer (score 2):

The `get` method on `Map[A,B]` returns an `Option[B]`. If there is an entry you will get `Some(element)` otherwise `None`. This is not like the java `get` on maps. `+` is not defined on options and that's why you get the error.

You can use the `apply` method if you are sure that the map contains the element. `m.apply("foo")` or with some sugar `m("foo")`.

Comment: "+ is not defined on options and that's why you get the error." true, but the actual error is due to an implicit conversion to `String` in order to try to apply a string-concatenating `+`. This (mis-)feature causes no end of hard-to-interpret errors.